# Placeholder not working with internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, placeholder

Little issue on my app, placeholders aren't present on Internet Explorer 11.

I tried the CSS sample below but without any success.

```
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE10–11 */
    color: #ccc !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: 400;
}

::placeholder { /* CSS Working Draft */
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Post the code required to reproduce the issue in your question

Comment: Seems like you did your CSS homework. The CSS should work, though the placeholder should work without it anyway. Post some html. Are you using it not in an input element?

Comment: Are you sure there is no JS making changes to the input?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found how to resolve this issue, the emulation was set at 9 as default on the debugger's screen even if internet explorer 11 was being used, so I added this on the head tag of the HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

Which changes the compatability format to IE11.