# placeholder text not displayed on IE with focus in

Tags: html, css, angular2-template

I am using an input field with placeholder in my angular2 app.

```
<input #searchEl type="search" placeholder="some text" autofocus>
```

The requirement is to keep focus in on the input field by default. However on IE, it looks like the placeholder text is not displayed when we focus in (not the case with chrome and firefox).

Is there any solution or workaround to this issue? Is there a way to still display placeholder text when we focus in the input field on IE? I am using IE 11

Comment: which version of IE and can you also put your code where you handle the focus.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I am using IE11 and Its same issue if I use autofocus (causing focus in in the input element by placing the cursor inside the box)

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118053/placeholder-not-working-with-internet-explorer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder not working with internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118053/placeholder-not-working-with-internet-explorer)

Comment: Farhan, It is not a duplicate of the issue you mentioned. My issue is that placeholder text is not displayed only when you focus in the input box. The issue you pointed relates to placeholder not displayed at all

Answer (score 0):

You should use `renderer2` library in order to manipulate DOM for best practices. If `focus` doesn't work try also `click`

```
`import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `
        <input #searchEl (focus)="keepPh()" type="search" placeholder="some text">
        <div> Some other content </div>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('searchEl') input: ElementRef;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    //Sets autofocus true when component's views are initialized
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.input.nativeElement, 'autofocus', true);
    }

    //Keeps place holder visible on input focus
    keepPh() {
        this.renderer.setAttribute(this.input.nativeElement, 'placeholder', 'some text');
    }
}`
```

You can also do this via `directives`

```
`import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appFocus]'
})
export class FocusDirective {

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

    toggleFlag: Boolean = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'focus', () => {

            this.toggleFlag = (this.toggleFlag === true) ? false : true;

            if (this.toggleFlag) {
                this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'placeholder', 'some text');
            } else {
                this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'placeholder', 'some text');
            }

        })
    }
}

//Use it like so:
<input type="search" placeholder="some text" appFocus>`
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue on IE. Have you tested on IE 11? On focus in, the placeholder is still not visible on IE

Comment: Have you tried both of them? After a bit searching, it seems like a bug. See it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445891/keep-placeholder-on-focus-in-ie10

Comment: Based on what I had read, it seems like IE behavior but I was hoping to find a simple workaround for this